# Can't override header.html file

Tags: javascript, mean-stack, mean.io

I have already overridden the default layouts and views. So I see the content of my own index.html file. But how come it loads the header.html from the system package? Why doesn't it load my own header.html which lives in my own package?

This is what I currently have in my own package: in server/views/layouts/default.html:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" data-ng-include="'/myTheme/views/header.html'" data-role="navigation"></div>
```

And this is how I have overridden the default layouts in my own package in app.js:

```
MyTheme.register(function(app, auth, database) {

  //We enable routing. By default the Package Object is passed to the routes
  MyTheme.routes(app, auth, database);

  //We are adding a link to the main menu for all authenticated users
  MyTheme.menus.add({
    title: 'myTheme example page',
    link: 'myTheme example page',
    roles: ['authenticated'],
    menu: 'main'
  });

  app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');

// More code..
```

And this is how I have overridden my public views in my own package in myTheme.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.myTheme',  ['mean.system']).config(['$viewPathProvider', '$stateProvider',
  function($viewPathProvider, $stateProvider) {
    $viewPathProvider.override('system/views/index.html', 'myTheme/views/index.html');
  }
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass System into your register function. Also, I would put the `app.set()` function as the first line of your register function.

From the docs:

> Please note that the package must depend on System to ensure it is evaluated after System and can thus override the views folder

```
MyPackage.register(function(system, app) {
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/server/views');
  // ...
```